# Smart pointers release in FinalRelease explicitly

Tags: c++, com, atl, raii

Some classes of project I'm working on look like this

```
class ATLCOMCLASS<CComObjectRootEx<ATLCOMCLASS> >
{
  ISomeInterfacePtr p;
  /*some stuff*/
  void FinalRelease()
  {
    p = NULL;
  }
}
```

`ISomeInterfacePtr` is defined by `_COM_SMARTPTR_TYPEDEF`. I don't understand why does it need to explicitly do `p = NULL` which means `p->Release()`, if this operation will be conducted in `ATLCOMCLASS` dtor automatically.

Could you exaplain me, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically, it doesn't *have* to do `p = NULL` at that point in the code, or explicitly at any point, because the destructor will release the smart pointer as you noted. However, explicitly releasing it gives you finer control over *when* it happens, which may be of use.

Depending on the requirements of `ISomeInterface`, the program, and other factors, releasing `p` before `this` is destroyed might satisfy some program condition. In particular, if `FinalRelease()` is called by another method and *not* the dtor, then the cleanup is happening somewhere else and likely has a very different trigger. It could also be cleaned up and then some resources recreated in a sort of reset, or any number of other sequences.

To figure out exactly why this is useful, assuming it's not a mistake, you'll need to work back up the possible program flow and see what's going on.